# Image Map not referenceable by ID?

Tags: html, browser, syntax, imagemap

I have an image and a map embedded as such:

```
<img src="planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="planetmap" />
<map id="planetmap">
  ...
```

It's NOT working. I tried using the `name` attribute for `map`:

```
<img src="planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap" />
<map name="planetmap">
  ...
```

And it worked! Even this:

```
<img src="planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap" />
<map id="planetmap">
  ...
```

worked, albeit only in IE9 and not in Chrome. Is it because Chrome doesn't support it or is it just because IE's engine is sloppy?

What am I doing wrong here? [W3Schools](http://w3schools.com/) [explicitly recommends](http://w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp) using the `id` attribute as opposed to `name`:

> Differences Between HTML and XHTML
>
> In XHTML, the name attribute of the  tag is deprecated, and will be removed. Use the > id attribute instead

My DOCTYPE is `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The name attribute for `<map>` is not deprecated. In fact, it's even a [part of the HTML5 specification for `<map>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-map-element.html#the-map-element).

Also XHTML != HTML5.
Finally, do not use W3schools as a reference. Instead, use the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/map).
To get quality documentation, prepend or append "mdn" to your keywords, e.g. ["mdn image map"](http://www.google.com/search?q=mdn%20image%20map).

Comment: Also [the `usemap` attribute](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/img.html#img.attrs.usemap) is explicitly defined as a [hash-name reference](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/datatypes.html#common.data.hash-name) in HTML5

Comment: MDN's reference is certainly comprehensive but very technical, I have found SitePoint to be much more accurate than W3c and more readable than MDN: http://reference.sitepoint.com/html

Comment: +1 for the "append 'mdn' to your search keywords". probably the best advice you can give to a web developer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put

```
....usemap="#planetmap" border=0 />
```

instead of

```
usemap="planetmap" />
```

in Firefox 11 it works.

Comment: That's what he did in the third example, didn't he?

Comment: @RobW Thanks for editing my post. Yeah, that's exactly what I did in the third example, but it still didn't work in Chrome :(